# laravel blade syntax for loop how to call iteration index inside laravel helper functions

Tags: laravel, validation, for-loop, laravel-blade, helper

I have the following for loop

```
@for($i = 0; $i < $contactAmount; $i++)
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="firstname" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">voornaam</label>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="firstname" type="text" class="form-control @error('firstname.0') is-invalid @enderror" name="firstname[]" value="{{ old('firstname.0') }}" autofocus>

                        @error('firstname.0')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
@endfor
```

but if I replace the hard coded '0' with {{ $i }} my validation does not work anymore. So how do I call my integer and use it inside laravel helper functions?

```
 @for($i = 0; $i < $contactAmount; $i++)
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="firstname" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">voornaam</label>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="firstname" type="text" class="form-control @error('firstname.{{ $i }}') is-invalid @enderror" name="firstname[]" value="{{ old('firstname.'. $i) }}" autofocus>

                        @error('firstname.{{ $i }}')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
@endfor
```

Comment: `@error('firstname.'.$i)` would be the correct syntax. `@error()` is already PHP, so adding `{{ }}` (opening/closing PHP) is wrong. You did it correctly for the `old()` helper: `old('firstname.'. $i)`

Comment: ah, thanks it worked! I was just trying things out but wasn't sure what would work and what wouldn't

Comment: Takes a bit to get used to, that's for sure. Knowing when you're working in PHP-land vs HTML-land comes with practice. :)

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use a `@foreach`? You can access the index of the loop as follows:

```
@foreach($contactAmount as $amount)
   <div class="form-group row">
       {{ $loop->iteration }}
       ...
   </div>
@endforeach
```